# Sampling repeatedly with different probability

Tags: r

In the following code "Weight" is a large matrix of weight sets. This matrix is consisted of let's say 1000 rows and 4 columns. Each row is a set of weights (sum of the elements in each row is equal to one).

In addition, there are four object and I want to select one of them based on the each weight sets. In other words, this random selection should be repeated for all of the weight sets.

Right now I have solved the problem with `for`. But is there any more efficient way to code it in R?

```
y <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
for(i in 1:nrow(Weight)){
  selection[i] <- sample(y, 1, prob=Weight[i,]) #selection is a vector with the same number of rows as Weight
}
```

Comment: How do you define "efficient"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `sample` into a function that lets you pass only one argument, a row from `Weight`:

```
myfun <- function(w) {
    sample(y, 1, prob=w)
}
```

Then you can use one of the apply family:

```
apply(Weight, 1, myfun)
```

However, so long as you have pre-allocated `selection` your method is not terribly inefficient.

Comment: alternatively, you can just use `apply` directly without creating an additional function:  `apply(Weight, 1, sample, x=y, size=1, replace=FALSE)`

Answer (score 5):

A more efficient way would be to first compute the row-wise cumulative sums of your weights then draw a number between `0` and `1` and see where it lands within that cumulative sum. This way, you only need to do **one** call to `runif` to get your random data, versus `1000` calls using other methods.

```
Weight <- matrix(sample(1:100, 1000 * 4, TRUE), 1000, 4)

x <- runif(nrow(Weight))
cumul.w <- Weight %*% upper.tri(diag(ncol(Weight)), diag = TRUE) / rowSums(Weight)
i <- rowSums(x > cumul.w) + 1L
selection <- y[i]
```

Also note how I computed the cumulative sums by multiplying by a triangular matrix instead of using the slower `apply(Weight, 1, cumsum)`. Everything is vectorized so it should be way faster than using an `apply` or `for` loop.

---

Benchmark comparison with `apply` and `for`:

```
f_runif <- function(Weight, y) {
  x <- runif(nrow(Weight))
  cumul.w <- Weight %*% upper.tri(diag(ncol(Weight)), diag = TRUE) /
    rowSums(Weight)
  i <- rowSums(x > cumul.w) + 1L
  y[i]
}

f_for <- function(Weight, y) {
  selection <- rep(NA, nrow(Weight))
  for(i in 1:nrow(Weight)){
    selection[i] <- sample(y, 1, prob=Weight[i,])
  }
}

f_apply <- function(Weight, y) {
  apply(Weight, 1, function(w)sample(y, 1, prob=w))
}

y <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
Weight <- matrix(sample(1:100, 1000 * 4, TRUE), 1000, 4)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f_runif(Weight, y),
               f_for  (Weight, y),
               f_apply(Weight, y))

# Unit: microseconds
#                expr       min        lq    median         uq       max neval
#  f_runif(Weight, y)   223.635   231.111   274.531   281.2165  1443.208   100
#    f_for(Weight, y) 10220.674 11238.660 11574.039 11917.1610 14583.028   100
#  f_apply(Weight, y)  9006.974 10016.747 10509.150 10879.9245 27060.189   100
```